# from keras.utils import print_summary ImportError: cannot import name 'print_summary' from 'keras.utils' error

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I Get An Error Like This:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\eminn\Desktop\Autopilot_V2\Train_pilot_V2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras.utils import print_summary
ImportError: cannot import name 'print_summary' from 'keras.utils' 
(C:\Users\eminn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py)
```

Code:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, Lambda
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from keras.utils import print_summary
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import keras.backend as K
import pickle

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

def keras_model(image_x, image_y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 127.5 - 1., input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='valid'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='valid'))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='valid'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mse")
    filepath = "Autopilot_10.h5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

    return model, callbacks_list


def loadFromPickle():
    with open("features", "rb") as f:
        features = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("labels", "rb") as f:
        labels = np.array(pickle.load(f))

    return features, labels


def main():
    features, labels = loadFromPickle()
    features, labels = shuffle(features, labels)
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(features, labels, random_state=0,
                                                        test_size=0.3)
    train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], 100, 100, 1)
    test_x = test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[0], 100, 100, 1)
    model, callbacks_list = keras_model(100, 100)
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), epochs=3, batch_size=32,
              callbacks=callbacks_list)
    print_summary(model)

    model.save('Autopilot_10.h5')
main()
K.clear_session();
```

I Downloaded Some Modules But Nothing Happened. I Have No Idea About How I Can Do It. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of TF you are using. Remove this line from the beginning of the code:

```
from keras.utils import print_summary
```

and then replace this line:

```
print_summary(model)
```

with:

```
model.summary()
```

Also, you can put it right after the model is compiled (before `model.fit()`).